# how to write string with outputstream(Telnet client) using java

Tags: java, outputstream

i tried to use this code but when i start the connection it seems that the server doesn't receive the string(the command):

```
public static void sendMessage(TelnetClient s, String myMessageString)
       throws IOException {
      OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);  
      oos.writeObject(myMessageString); 
      }
```

i tried also to use only the outputstream and to do the following thing:

```
os.write(myMessageString.getbytes());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use `ObjectOutputStream` - that will use binary serialization that your telnet server won't be expecting.

It would be best to create an `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
// Adjust the encoding to whatever you want, but you need to decide...
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
writer.write(myMessageString);
writer.flush();
```

The `flush` call may well be what was missing before - depending on exactly what `TelnetClient` does, it may be buffering the data until you flush the stream.

Comment: what does the flush() method do ?